# Xamarin Form: Swipe Gesture on Relative Layout

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin App which I am trying to add swipe gesture recogniser to a Relative Layout via Custom Renderer.

```
public class MainPageCarouselRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<RelativeLayout>
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer asd;
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer asd2;

    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<RelativeLayout> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);

        asd = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer (() => {
            e.NewElement.TranslateTo (0, -150, 500, Easing.BounceOut);
        });

        asd.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Up;
        asd2 = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer (() => {

            e.NewElement.TranslateTo (0, 0, 500, Easing.BounceOut);
        });

        asd2.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down;
        this.AddGestureRecognizer (asd);
        this.AddGestureRecognizer (asd2);
    }



}
```

this is the code in my IOS Renderer. I debugged this piece of code and breakpoint that I put here got hit. But when I put breakpoint inside the

```
            asd2 = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer (() => {

            e.NewElement.TranslateTo (0, 0, 500, Easing.BounceOut);
        });
```

or the other one it doesn't get hit. Any ideas?